# laravel-4 way to inject an object that requires configuration into a controller

Tags: laravel, laravel-4

I would like to find a good way to pass a pre-configured object to a controller. I know that I can use the IoC like below:

```
Mycontroller extends extends \Illuminate\Routing\Controllers\Controller {

    //i can only use one config uless i pass Request data
    $this->config = App::make('MyconfigObject');

}
```

but this seems to have the limitation of only being able to use one config. I would rather do something like the following:

```
Route::get('some-route', function()
{
    $config = Config::get('some.config');
    $object = new MyConfigObject($config);
    Route::dispatch(MyController($object));
});
```

The reason I would like to do this is that I would like to dispatch the same controller, but with different configuration for several routes.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not totally satisfied with this method but its the best I've come up with so far, using the IoC's automatic resolution.

bootstrap/stat.php

```
/*
* bindings to the IoC container
*/
$app->singleton('MyNamespace\Transfer\TransferStategyInterface', function() {
    $config = Config::get('transfer-strategy');
    return new LocalTransferStrategy($config);
});


use MyNamespace\Transfer\TransferStategyInterface;
```

TransferController.php

```
use MyNamespace\Transfer\TransferStategyInterface;


class TransferController extends BaseController {

    protected $transferStrategy;

    public function __construct(TransferStategyInterface $transferStrategy = null)
    {
        $this->transferStrategy = $transferStrategy;
    }
}
```

Comment: I used to use your approach before. Now I use `App::make()` to instantiate objects directly in the method. This way you don't need to create objects that won't be needed in certain methods and keeps your Controller simple. Other tip: I don't use backslaskes in my app bindings. I let that to the automatic resolution. I use dots like `App::make('my.special.method', array($arg1, $arg2))`. This way I can have several constructors of the same class with a descriptive instantiation