# Laravel Bind Object Interface with an implementation that has variables parameters in it's constructor

Tags: php, laravel, domain-driven-design, laravel-5, service-provider

Please note that before aksing this questions I've looked into:

[laravel-4 way to inject an object that requires configuration into a controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15483542/laravel-4-way-to-inject-an-object-that-requires-configuration-into-a-controller)

[Laravel 4: Passing data from make to the service provider](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595760/laravel-4-passing-data-from-make-to-the-service-provider)

and

[Laravel 4: Confused about how to use App::make()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21680795/laravel-4-confused-about-how-to-use-appmake)

But I cannot see that they answer my question!

Domain Model:
A Site must have an Owner and currently this owner is of type Customer but can change in the future to be a Reseller or an Employee etc.. so I'm using Polymorphism as follows:

class Site has an Owner Property.
Owner is an interface,
Customer is a class which implements Owner,
Customer has a Name and a Uid therefore these are required in the constructor of Customer.

Now I want to bind the Customer implementation to the Owner interface so that whenever I call Owner I get a Customer.

We would normally do this:

```
class UseCustomerAsSiteOwnerServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider{

    public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('hidden\Domain\Model\Site\Owner', function ($app)
        {
            return $this->app->make(new Customer());
        });


    }

}
```

However Customer() requires $id and $name to be initialized and these are variable objects -  not static so I don't know how to pass them?

I tried this:

```
public function register()
    {
        $this->app->bind('hidden\Domain\Model\Site\Owner', function ($app) use ($id, $name)
        {
            return $this->app->make(new Customer($id, $name));
        });


    }
```

But in this case the $name and $id in the USE statement are not defined. Anyone has ideas?

UPDATE:
The Customer Constructor is as follows:

```
    /**
     * Initialise a new Customer
     *
     * @param Identifier $id
     * @param CustomerName $name
     */
    public function __construct(Identifier $id, $name)
    {
        $this->id       =       $this->setId($id);
        $this->name     =       $this->setName($name);
    }
```

This will be initialized from an Aggregate root (Site). The correct types will be passed to it.

Comment: You are passing them into the closure correctly, they aren't defined because you never defined them before the closure.  Where exactly are `$id` and `$name` coming from and what do you mean by `variable objects`?

Comment: @user3158900 I updated the question with more information. What I mean is that both the Id and the Name will vary in values depending on which Customer we want to initialize. The example questions i found all use static values as parameters so it's easy to use them in Service Provider.

Answer (score 0):

Since I don't think it's possible to pass variables, I decided to remove the constructor from the Customer and set it's properties using custom methods so that now I can say:

$this->owner->setId(Identifier Id). The service provider will resolve Owner to its Customer implementation.